# React: How do I execute code whenever a route is activated?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-router, and I want to execute code (to start a timer) whenever a route such as "/#/home" is activated.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the static method `willTransitionTo`. It fires right before the route loads the component. [Route Handler](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Route%20Handler)

A better solution might be to add some code in your router to capture the timestamp then pass it down to the routed component...

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  var runTime = new Date();
  React.render(<Root runTime={runTime}/>, document.body);
});
```

Then in your `componentDidMount` determine the number of seconds between the now and `this.props.runTime` and fire off a counter to keep track of time after that.

Answer (score 1):

With [react-routing](http://www.kriasoft.com/react-routing) library it may looks something like this:

```js
const router = new Router(on => {

  on('*', async (state, next) => {
    console.log('start: load the child component');
    const component = await next();
    console.log('end: load the child component');
    return <App>{component}</App>;
  });

  on('/hello', async () => <HelloComponent />);

});

router.dispatch({path: '/hello'}, component =>
   React.render(component, document.body)
);
```

Or, here is an example, how to do the same without using any 3rd party routing libraries:

[image: img]
https://twitter.com/koistya/status/609762956646219776